# How can I add a loader before api request completed in Vue SPA

Tags: api, vue.js, routes, axios, loader

I have made a vue SPA and when I go to a new route the page will load before my request to the server is complete meaning there will be a 0.5s delay or so before the data shows. I'd like to add a loader such as NProgress that only goes to the page once the request is complete and the everything is loaded making it so the data will appear instantly instead of my elements being empty then data appearing after a delay.

How would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use an isLoading boolean to conditionally render the progress bar when true, and the rest of your component if false.

I see you have axios mentioned. Unlikely, but if you aren't making any more API calls after the initial page load, you could create interceptors in your axios instance that set a piece of vuex state as true when the request begins, and false when it finishes. You could then just conditionally render your progress bar in App.vue when true, and your router-view when false.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '@/store'

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'URL',
})

api.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    store.commit('changeLoadingStatus', true)
    return config
  }, error => {
    // Handle errors
})

api.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    store.commit('changeLoadingStatus', false)
    return response
  }, error => {
    // Handle errors
})

export default api
```

Comment: Do you have a link to any docs that could be helpful for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself but maybe you can try something like this

```
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
      { path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home },
      { path: '/about', name: 'about', component: About }
  ]
})

router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
    // If this isn't an initial page load.
    if (to.name) {
        // Start the route progress bar.
        NProgress.start()
    }
    next()
})

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    // Complete the animation of the route progress bar.
    NProgress.done()
})
```